# Error after upgrading Android Studio NDK: CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

After updating Android Studio NDK, I can't build my app, due to an error related to CMAKE (my application uses one c++ file).
Here are the error lines:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\AnimallTag\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Projetos\Git\at65\app -BC:\Projetos\Git\at65\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\mips -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=mips -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\AnimallTag\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Projetos\Git\at65\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\mips -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\AnimallTag\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\AnimallTag\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-14}
 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Any suggestion to help me solve that problem? Maybe a way I can downgrade NDK or a Android Studio previous version I can install...

[image: Error screen in Android Studio]

Comment: the solutions provided did not work for me. starting a bounty.

Answer (score 11):

I managed to fix it. One thing I noticed was the changelog of android NDK, and it says there is no more support for armeabi, MIPS and MIPS64 ABIs, so I filtered ABIs in my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that I synchronized gradle and Android Studio prompted me to update Gradle, and I did.
The app can now be deployed, but I'm not sure what fixed it.
Apparently the error was not related to CMAKE_C_COMPILER neither CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER, it was happening somewhere else and when the build failed, it wasn't able to find those variables.
Maybe this can help someone too...

Comment: Actually, this is taken care of by the new gradle plugin. In **build.gradle**, set `buildscript { dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' } }` and in **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**, `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`.

Comment: the solutions provided did not work for me. starting a bounty.

Comment: @user1506104 do you see exactly same error message? Do you use NDK r17? Did you delete the **.externalNativeBuild** to clear cmake cache?

Comment: Yes. Cleared the build folder as well.

Answer (score 5):

After NDK Recent update CMAKE was breaking

**Nothing Worked but** I downgraded NDK by downloading NDK from 
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

and changed NDK DIR PATH in **local.properties** to

```
ndk.dir=/Users/kathan/Library/Android/sdk/android-ndk-r17c
```

And just Sync Gradle.

Worked like Charm

Comment: Perfect! Solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had two installation folders for NDK. I needed to update my **local.properties** to point to the correct directory. I updated my NDK and **build.gradle** (thru answers above), re-synced then everything worked okay.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I faced similar kind of issue after installing **ndk-bundle**,
Error was solved in following way:

Add following code snippet in **build.gradle** file (**module level**):

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
       ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            }
        }
      }
}
```

**Note:** If you already have this kind of code in build.gradle file then please make ensure that there is no extra **abiFilters** instead those I mention here.

Also make sure you have added:
**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip**

in  **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** file.

Thanks!
Happy Coding :)